# XSD unique constraint on attribute of sibling elements of a specific type

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, unique

I have an XML document structured as Q&A which follows the following format (edited for clarity):

```
<question>
    <answer id="1">
        <question>
            <answer id="1"/>
            <answer id="2"/>
            <answer id="3"/>
        </question>
    </answer>
    <answer id="2">
        <question>
            <answer id="1"/>
            <answer id="2"/>
        </question>
    </answer>
</question>
```

My XSD looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="question">
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="answer" type="answerType" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="AnswerIdUnique">
        <xs:selector xpath="./*" />
        <xs:field xpath="@id" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="answerType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="question" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

There is, of course, more to it than what you see above but this illustrates my problem.
I need for the `id` attribute on `answer` elements to be unique among siblings. The XSD defined above enforces uniqueness of `id` attributes among sibling elements, but it does not discriminate on element type. I've tried a variety of selectors and fields in the unique constraint, but have not found a combination that works.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just change the selector to `<xs:selector xpath="answer"/>` and you'll be fine. In general it is good to avoid XPaths like `.//*`, if only for performance reasons.

This is the XML Schema for the XML sample you've provided that I think is working the way you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="question" type="questionType">
        <xs:unique name="AnswerIdUnique">
            <xs:selector xpath="answer"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="questionType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="answer" type="answerType" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="answerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="question" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Your posted XML validates fine with the above; duplicating any sibling answer's id yields a validation error. For example, the following XML:

```
<question> 
    <answer id="1"> 
        <question> 
            <answer id="1"/> 
            <answer id="2"/> 
            <answer id="1"/> 
        </question> 
    </answer> 
    <answer id="1"> 
        <question> 
            <answer id="1"/> 
            <answer id="2"/> 
        </question> 
    </answer> 
</question>
```

When validated (in QTAssistant, should be similar to the message in Visual Studio since it is based on the same technology), these are the errors:

```
Error occurred while loading [], line 6 position 5
There is a duplicate key sequence '1' for the 'AnswerIdUnique' key or unique identity constraint.
Error occurred while loading [], line 9 position 3
There is a duplicate key sequence '1' for the 'AnswerIdUnique' key or unique identity constraint.
Document1.xml is invalid.
```

Below is a screenshot from Visual Studio 2010 showing the above XML validation against the XSD I've posted; while the problems are inadvertently reported as warnings, they are, nonetheless, reported.

[image: VS2010 showing unique constraint errors]

I've randomly picked an online validator (http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/) and validated the same XML and XSD I've posted; the error is reported as:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Duplicate unique value [1] declared for identity constraint of element "question".org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Duplicate unique value [1] declared for identity constraint of element "question".`

One thing you have to pay attention to is when you have a target namespace for your XSD; in that case, it is needed to define an alias for all of the involved namespaces, and use them in your selectors.

UPDATE: And the XSD with namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://localhost" xmlns="http://localhost" targetNamespace="http://localhost" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="question" type="questionType">
        <xs:unique name="AnswerIdUnique">
            <xs:selector xpath="tns:answer"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="questionType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="answer" type="answerType" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="answerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="question" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Please notice the introduction of the `tns` prefix and the use of it in the selector.

Comment: Petru, what software are you using to work with the XML and validate it against the schema?

Comment: Hi @jm2, [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com), a product I am associated with. It is built on .NET, hence my comment it should work the same with Visual Studio's. Actually, I just tried it in VS 2010 and it gives the same messages (albeit shown as Warnings).

Comment: Petru, I tried your suggestions with XMLSpy and got the same results and warnings as with VS2010.

Comment: @jm2, so what is the question then? Isn't the XSD I posted what you've wanted? If not, can you please explain what is it that doesn't meet your needs? Maybe show an invalid XML that is not properly flagged?

Comment: Petru, I've tested the code you posted and the schema still does not enforce the unique constraint. This is still true for vs2010 and xmlspy. I've even tried an online xml validator and the schema does not work as expected with it either. The only software package that seems to work as you say is the one you are using.

Comment: @jm2, what do you mean by "does not enforce"? Is it in the fact that you're getting warnings instead of errors, say in Visual Studio? Or that it still parses the XML?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10815/discussion-between-petru-gardea-and-jm2)

Comment: +1 for adding the bit about the necessary alias when declaring a targetNamespace. Where is that documented?

Comment: @michielvoo, thank you; I don't recall seeing this documented, it is rather my own experience being shared. I remember reading the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-identity-constraint) and trying to see the reason why someone would implement it as such first time I ran into it. What I thought then was that dealing with scenarios where the default xmlns equals the target namespace of the schema (said to be best practice) and element particles where the form is unqualified would certainly benefit from this approach... so I left it at that...