# Schema xs:unique is not being validated

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, unique

I have a simple xml file

```xml
<form xmlns="http://www.example.org/form-reader/form-description"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/form-reader/form-description form-description.xsd">
    <pages amount="1"/>
    <pages amount="1"/>
</form>
```

And i wrote schema for it

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/form-reader/form-description"
xmlns="http://www.example.org/form-reader/form-description"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="pagesType">
    <xs:attribute name="amount" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="formType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="pages" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
        type="pagesType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="form" type="formType">
    <xs:unique name="pageNumberUnique">
        <xs:selector xpath="pages" />
        <xs:field xpath="@amount" />
    </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to validate uniqness of amount property, but in all validators, my xml file seems valid and it shouldn't, why?

## Solution

My schema after applying @PetruGardea fix looks like this:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/form-reader/form-description"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/form-reader/form-description"
xmlns="http://www.example.org/form-reader/form-description"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="pagesType">
    <xs:attribute name="amount" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="formType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="pages" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
    type="pagesType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="form" type="formType">
    <xs:unique name="pageNumberUnique">
    <xs:selector xpath="tns:pages" />
    <xs:field xpath="@amount" />
    </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define an alias for your targetNamespace and use that in your xpath for selectors and fields. See this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356723/xsd-unique-constraint-on-attribute-of-sibling-elements-of-a-specific-type/10358114#10358114), and read the post and the comments I made for more details.