# how to add unique constraint in this case?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have the following XSD snippet:

```
<xs:complexType name="JsonLayout">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="ns:LayoutTypeBase">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="attribute" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="ns:nonEmptyString" />
                        <xs:attribute name="layout" use="required" type="ns:nonEmptyString" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

This extends LayoutTypeBase which is just empty:

```
<xs:complexType name="LayoutTypeBase" />
```

In JsonLayout, I want to add a unique constraint to make sure they don't specify 2 attributes with the same name.

VS doesn't let me add a unique contraint anywhere here except for the inner element. But thats not going to hit the "collection", its going to hit the element itself right? And I need it to be on the "collection".

I tried wrapping the complexType in an element and shifting the name to the element and then I was able to add a unique constraint, but it didn't trigger an error when I had a dupe name:

```
<xs:element name="JsonLayout">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ns:LayoutTypeBase">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="attribute" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="ns:nonEmptyString" />
                            <xs:attribute name="layout" use="required" type="ns:nonEmptyString" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="jsonLayout.uniqueAttributeName">
        <xs:selector xpath="attribute" />
        <xs:field xpath="@name" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

What's the correct xpath syntax here? Or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What I want to know is - why isn't JsonLayout included in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/log4j-2.11.1/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem must be that your schema has a targetNamespace. Because of this, you must define a prefix for that namespace (e.g. tns), and use that prefix with your selector (tns:attribute).

Just for completeness, in your scenario you could use xs:key as well (instead of unique) since your selector and field point to mandatory content.

If you think about asking why you need an alias, please go through this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356723/xsd-unique-constraint-on-attribute-of-sibling-elements-of-a-specific-type/10358114#10358114), the UPDATE section (showing syntax with namespaces).

Based on your comment, this may match your scenario:

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xtm="http://paschidev.com/schemas/metadata/xtm">
    <xs:complexType name="JsonLayout">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="LayoutTypeBase">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="attribute" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="layout" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LayoutTypeBase"/>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="k">
            <xs:selector xpath="*/tns:attribute"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Sample (invalid) XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xtm="http://paschidev.com/schemas/metadata/xtm" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <some xsi:type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="a" layout="b"/>
        <attribute name="a" layout="b"/>
    </some>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. Apparently, I can't wrap the type in an element. It is required to be xs:complexType. It is used as layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" (i.e. type extension). No where to stick a xs:key or xs:unique then?

Comment: If by "this doesn't work" you mean wrap the type in an element, and you actually rely on xsi:type, then XSD integrity constraints may not work for you. As for the XPath syntax, it should work (beside the missing prefix, all else is good). Maybe... if there is some other parent element that wraps all other ones relying on xsi:type, and if path //tns:attribute or */tns:attribute, etc. doesn't run into anything that's not supposed to match, then try to define it at that level; see the updated post.

Comment: yes, I am using xsi:type. What you did in your updated example, was you put the constraint on "root", that does work... I was trying to put the constraint as part of JsonLayout itself so it can be reused. LayoutTypeBase is re-used probably like 50 times throughout the schema :). So I would have to C&P the key/unique 50 times :(. Any way to package it inside of the reusable object?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Identity constraints require an element.